# Best figure size adjustment when dealing with different image sizes

Tags: beamer, graphics, scaling

I have a script which automatically creates a `beamer` presentation with several `.ps` images, each one inserted in a distinct frame. Those images consist on graphs built using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). The script is basically iterating on this code snippet:

```
\begin{frame}{Image 1}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image-1.ps}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

I have some images with large widths, like this one (reduced the size and quality for best viewing):

[image: An image with large width]

So the above code works like a charm. But I do have small images as well, like this one:

[image: A small image]

If I leave the `\includegraphics` command with no adjustments, my images will become way bigger than the frame itself. If I put `width=1\textwidth`, it will work fine with large width images, but not with small ones.

Is there a way to find the best figure size adjustment when using `\includegraphics`, so my images will be displayed correctly? I usually do that manually, but in this case it's a script which simply adds the image to the `.tex` body and compile it. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, but couldn't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides the boolean value `keepaspectratio`. It's explained in the [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) as follow:

> If set to true then specifying both `width` and `height` (or `totalheight`) does not distort the figure but scales such that neither of the specified dimensions is exceeded.

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{picture}
```

Comment: `keepaspectratio` is a new one for me.  Exactly what I need, too.

Comment: Just in case someone needs the same for text: The `adjustbox` package allows to use `\adjustbox[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{<text>}`. You might want to use `totalheight` instead of `height`. Alternatievly you can use `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<text>}` (or `\resizebox*` to use `totalheight` instead) but this requires `\Gin@isotrue` locally to enable the `keepaspectratio` feature. You could write is as `\csname Gin@isotrue\endcsname` to avoid issues with the `@`.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the update! I'd probably ask the very same thing for text, you read my mind. Living and learning. =)

Comment: @Marco @Martin Is there something similar for floats? If I use  `\begin{figure}[p]  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{picture}  \caption{somecaption}  \end{figure}`  then the graphic will be scaled to fit the page, but the float might still produce an `overfull hbox` because of the caption.

Comment: @Janek: This shouldn't happen except the caption contains some strange content which can't be broken or hyphenated correctly. Also, try loading the `caption` package to get smarter captions.

Comment: @Martin It seems I alwas get the warning even when I make a MWE with just one figure in it:  `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{AnyGraphic}
\caption{Some random caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}` will result in a `Float too large for page` warning.

Comment: @Janek: The `height=\textheight` is the problem. It doesn't leave any space for the caption. Try `height=\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip-\abovecaptionskip-\belowcaptionskip\relax` instead.

Comment: @Martin This indeed works for the very short caption. A longer (multiple lines) caption though, will still result in the warning.

Comment: @Janek: You need to adjust the height according to the height of the caption. You can get the height of the caption by storing it into a box first. If you post a follow-up question I will post a full answer.

Comment: @Martin Done. [Fit float to page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121335)