# Beamer - Optimal figure size given there is a caption, frametitle, etc

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats

This question is inspired by an almost [complete solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17380/best-figure-size-adjustment-when-dealing-with-different-image-sizes). My aim is to have the figure (placed in a `figure` environment) occupy the maximum place possible given that it has a caption (without generating any warnings of course) and that there are things like a frame title and a navigation bar. The idea from the linked solution is to use

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{picture}
```

However, this doesn't seem to take into account the fact that I have a frame title and a navigation bar (due to the Warsaw theme). Actually, even if I remove the theme, the frame title and the caption, it still results in a badbox. I've tried compiling with `PDFLaTeX` and `lualatex` from inside Texmaker.

Suggestions using additional packages (I already use `tikz`) or even `lua` are welcome. Here's the MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{General considerations}

\begin{frame}{Definition}

  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{statesOfMatter}
    \caption{Classical picture of the states of matter.}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\section{Placeholder I}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\section{Placeholder II}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure only]
[image: Figure surrounded by navigation bar, caption and frame title]

Comment: Please see this excellent answer from diabonas: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44298/3954 .

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that one out, I had completely missed it. It's a step too involved for my skills, but it seems that if I use `height=\dimexpr\contentheight-\contentbottom-X\baselineskip\relax`, where X=3 if there's a one-line caption and 0 otherwise, then I get a good enough size without a badbox (if the picture is higher than it is wide). It's a bit black magic to me, but I'll try delving into it a bit more these next few days.