# Fit float to page

Tags: floats, scaling

This is a follow-up question to [Best figure size adjustment when dealing with different image sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17380).
I want to resize a figure in a way, that the figure including the caption fits the page. Resizing just the figure has been explained in the previously mentioned question. The solution looked as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}  
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{AnyGraphic}  
\caption{Some random caption. This should be long enough to create at least one line break, as the overall size of the float naturally depends on the size of the caption}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Without the caption, everything is fine. But including a caption will result in a `Float too large for page` warning.
Thus the question: How can I fit a float including the caption to a page?
Note: I want to do this for many floats with captions of different lengths. I would thus prefer a solution that works for captions of arbitrary lengths.

Comment: Not an exact answer to this question, but it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439837/2961878

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use both `width` and `height` then you also almost always want to use `keepaspectratio` otherwise the image will be distorted to match the specified dimensions. For the rest you can do something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}  
\centering  

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip-\abovecaptionskip-\belowcaptionskip\relax,
keepaspectratio]{ug}  
\caption{Some random caption. This should be long enough to create at least one linebreak, as the overall size of the float naturally depends on the size of the caption}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Or you could measure the caption. I would get a warning that the float is too large by  0.04385pt which looks suspiciously like the depth, but rather than worry about that I
just subtracted an extra `2pt` for luck. `keepaspectratio` is commented out so that my test image stretches in this direction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newsavebox\cpsave 
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}  
\centering  
\savebox\cpsave{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\vspace*{\abovecaptionskip}%
\caption{Some random caption. This sholud be long enough to create at least one linebreak, as the overall size of the float naturally depends on the size of the caption}\end{minipage}}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\dimexpr\textheight-\ht\cpsave-\dp\cpsave-\lineskip-2pt\relax,
%keepaspectratio
]{ug}  

\noindent\usebox\cpsave
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I usually use `keepaspectratio`, but to reproduce the warning with ANY figure, I omitted it here, as a wide (width > height) figure would not result in this warning with `keepaspectratio`. As foor your solution: It works with this caption, but a longer caption will again produce the warning.

Comment: @Janek yes the alternative is to set the caption first in a box and measure it, but do you really need all the images to be that big, if so use `\newsavebox\foo` in the preamble `\savebox\foo{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\caption{....` before the image use image then subtract `-\ht\foo-\dp\foo` in your calculation and use `blank line \noindent\usebox\foo` after the figure.

Comment: As the used graphics are larger than the a4 page but contain some important details, I would prefer them to be as large as possible. Could you edit the new suggestions into your original answer? When I tried it here, I still got a warning.

Comment: @Janek updated answer