# Force two big images to fit a page

Tags: floats, subfloats, scaling, includegraphics

I have two big figures which I'd like to fit on a page, above each other and including their captions. Unfortunately the caption of the bottom figure sticks out.

I have tried using the subfigure package to at least force them on one page, but then it is still necessary to tweak the settings manually using the width or height parameter of

```
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
```

which is inconvenient if either the figure or the caption changes.
Are there any solutions automatically scaling the width parameter for everything to fit on the page?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: maybe this answer could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121347/36296